# NotifyPropertyChanged syntax (windows store app)

Tags: c#, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class:

```
namespace Golf
{
    public class Game : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Player
        {
            get { return Player; }
            set
            {
                Player = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Player");
            }
        }
        public int Hole
        {
            get { return Hole; }
            set
            {
                Hole = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Hole");
            }
        }
        public int Strokes
        {
            get { return Strokes; }
            set
            {
                Strokes = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Strokes");
            }
        }

        public Game(string player, int hole, int strokes)
        {
            Player = player;
            Hole = hole;
            Strokes = strokes;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my MainPage's constructor I fill the listview:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        // Left out other code
        listViewGames.ItemsSource = games;
    }
```

In my xaml I have the listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewGames" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateGames}"></ListView>
```

And the code of a click event that adds the game to the list of games:

```
Game game = new Game(listViewPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString(), Int32.Parse(listViewHoles.SelectedItem.ToString()), (int)sliderStrokes.Value);
            games.Add(game);
```

However the syntax in my class seems to be faulty, I get an error: System.StackOverflowException occured in ...

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You should post full exception trace

Comment: StackOverflowException was unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Golf.exe

That's all I get..

Edit: The error appears on the first bracket of the first set.

Answer (score 0):

Because you return the same property :)
Replace this:

```
public string Player
{
    get { return Player; }
    set
    {
        Player = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Player");
    }
}
```

with:

```
private string _player;
public string _player
{
    get { return _player; }
    set
    {
        _player = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Player");
    }
}
```

And others